# What are the CSS Properties position:center and position:page being used for?

Tags: html, css

The w3 specifies these two properties here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#center-pos

however I am not a native speaker and find their descriptions very cryptic. Can someone explain what these properties exactly do and what they can be used for?

Comment: Which two properties you mean here? I can see more than two there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From W3C spec [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-positioning/#position-property) it appears that these are new 'proposed' values for the `position` property not yet implemented.

> **Center**
>
> The box's position (and possibly size) is specified with the top, right, bottom, and left properties. **The box is vertically and horizontally centered within its containing block** (*my emphasis*) and these properties specify offsets with respect to the box's centered position within its containing block. Center positioned boxes are taken out of the normal flow. This means they have no impact on the layout of later siblings. Though center positioned boxes may have margins, those margins do not collapse with any other margins.

and

> **Page**
>
> The box's position is calculated according to the "absolute" model.
>
> In the case of **paged media** or when inside a **region box** the box's containing block is always the initial containing block.
>
> Otherwise, the containing block is determined per the "absolute" model.
> As with the "absolute" model, the box's margins do not collapse with any other margins. In the case of the print media type, the box is rendered only on the initial page or region where the page positioned element originated. User agents may paginate the content of paged boxes.

Comment: Where does it actually say that those features are only proposed and not implemented yet?

Comment: The title of the linked document is "W3C **Working Draft** 03 February 2015"

Answer (score 0):

**Let's say you have a `<p class="center">` element and its parent is an `<article>` element.**

> - The `p.center {position: center}` rule will put the `<p class="center">` element in the center of the `<article>` element.
> - `<p class="center">` will not follow the normal flow: it means that any other element in the `<article>` element will be overwritten with
>     the content in the `<p class="center">` element. If you specify a
>     `z-index` to `p.center` higher then the other elements in the
>     `<article>`, it will display on top of the them, hiding the content
>     below it.
> - You can offset the `<p class="center">` element from its initial centered position with the top, right, bottom and left properties.

**Let's say you have a `<p class="page">` element and its parent is an
`<article>` element.**

> - The `p.page {position: page}` rule will set the `<p class="page">` element as the same position of the `<article>` element.
> - `<p class="page">` will not follow the normal flow: it means that any other element in the `<article>` element will be overwritten with
>     the content in the `<p class="page">` element. If you specify a
>     `z-index` to `p.page` higher then the other elements in the
>     `<article>`, it will display on top of the them, hiding the content
>     below it.
> - You can offset the `<p class="page">` element from its initial position with the top, right, bottom and left properties.

Comment: according to Paulie_D these features are not implemented yet, reading your answer it seems you have been using them though. Did you?

Comment: No, Paulie_D is right. They are not yet implemented. But wanted to give MrKainig a better understanding of the "position" CSS property